# Using the fundamental theorems of calculus to prove the following

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-writing

How do I use the fundamental theorems of calculus to prove the following statements?

$\frac{d}{dx} \int f(x)dx = f(x)$

$\int \left( \frac{d}{dx} f(x) \right) dx = f(x) + C$

I've tried to combine the first and second theorems together, however, I can only end up with definite integrals.

I've been trying to prove this as it was mentioned in James Stewart's Calculus textbook (8th edition):

> Taken together, the two parts of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
> say that differentiation and integration are inverse processes. Each undoes what the
> other does.

However, there is no specific proof about this. Can someone help me with this proof?

Comment: If you integrate and then differentiate then you get the original function, if you differentiate and then integrate, you get the original function up to a constant. So they undo each other.

Comment: Both the assertions in your question are trivially true since the naked integral sign means just "this is a function with the integrand as derivative". The fundamental theorem of calculus (either version) relates _definite_ integrals and derivatives. So it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: You may find the proofs on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, the statement of the fundamental theorem of calculus you present is not accurate. The fundamental theorem of calculus is specifically a statement about Riemann integrals, or extensions thereof, and it only applies when the function being integrated satisfies certain conditions.

**First part of the theorem:** Let $f$ be a function on $[a,b]$ that is continuous almost everywhere. Then $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt=f(x)$$ for every $x$ on $]a,b[$.

**Second part of the theorem:** Let $f$ be a function on $[a,b]$ that is Riemann integrable. If there exists some $F$ on $]a,b[$ such that $\frac{dF}{dx}=f$, then $$\int_a^bf(t)dt=F(b)-F(a).$$

The first part of the theorem states, rather informally, that the derivative "inverts" integration. The second part of the theorem states, rather informally, that the integral "inverts" differentiation.

The second part of the theorem can be more suitably expressed as, let $f$ be a function on $[a,b]$ that is differentiable, and let $f'=\frac{df}{dx}$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Then $$\int_a^b\frac{df}{dx}(x)dx=f(b)-f(a).$$

Anyway, as you can see, neither of the statements you presented in your post is actually part of the fundamental theorem of calculus. Your first statement is merely saying: if there exists some $F$ on $]a,b[$ such that $\frac{dF}{dx}=f$, then $F$ is such that $\frac{dF}{dx}=f$ on $]a,b[$, which is obviously true. Your second statement is saying that, if $f$ is differentiable on $]a,b[$, then $\frac{d}{dx}(f)=\frac{d}{dx}(f + C)$, which is also obviously true, albeit less so; and neither of these has any particular relationship to the fundamental theorem of calculus, as they are just obvious statements.